# convergence of a series of function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find the set of pointwise and uniform convergence of this series:
$\sum x(1-x)^n$.
The set of pointwise convergence is $[0,2)$.
But for the uniform convergence what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

For the uniform convergence let

$$R_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x(1-x)^k$$
so by the sum of the geometric sequence we get for $0<a<b<2$

$$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|R_n(x)|=\max(|1-a|^{n+1},|1-b|^{n+1})\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1$$
so the given series is uniformly convergent on every interval $[a,b]\subset (0,2)$.

**Remark**$\quad$ From $(1)$ we can see that the series is not uniformly convergent on $[0,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric series:

$$|1-x|<1\iff -1<1-x<1\iff  -2<-x<0\iff0<x<2$$

and then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x(1-x)^n=x\frac1{1-(1-x)}=1$$

and our function, unexpectedly (for me, at least), is the constant function $\;g(x)=1\;,\;\;x\in (0,2)$

But the series obviously and boringly converges for $\;x=0\;$ , whereas for $\;x=2\;$ we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\cdot(-1)^n$$

and this last doesn't converge as $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cdot(-1)^n\neq 0\;$ In fact, the limit doesn't even exist.

The convergence interval thus is $\;[0,2-\delta)\;$, and uniform convergence exists in $\;(\epsilon,2)\;$ , for any $\;\epsilon\,,\,\delta>0\;$ s.t. $\;[\epsilon\,,\,2-\delta]\subset (0,2)\;$ .

Comment: Of course, @DavidMitra. Edited. Thanks.